# List of different record ids from a table for a given customer id (DB2)

Tags: sql, db2

I need to generate a list of different record ids from a table for a given customer id . 
Records with same record ids for a given customer id can be discarded.
records with one record id for a customer id can also be discarded.
The output should be like if for a given customer id, there are three different record ids then all the record ids will be populated.

I am facing errors with my SQL

```
select a.* 
from table a 
where a.customer_id = (select customer_id
                         from table
                         where customer_id = a.customer_id 
                         AND a.record_id <> record_id)
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  Your conditions are contradictory.

Comment: you most likely need `where a.customer_id IN (...)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `customer_id`, `record_id` pairs in the data, then you can use a much simpler query:

```
select distinct customer_id, record_id
from @T00120.table a ;
```